# urlrewriter.net The element 'rewrtie' is not allowed

Tags: asp.net, urlrewriter.net

i am trying to use urlrewriter.net and i followed instructions [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) but when i run it i get this error:

```
The element 'rewrtie' is not allowed.
```

here is what i added in my web.config file:

```
<httpModules>
    <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
</httpModules>

<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule" />
</modules>

  <configSections>
  <section name="rewriter"
            requirePermission="false"
            type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
```

```
<rewriter>
    <rewrtie url="~/User/Ahmed/ahmed.aspx" to="~/User/ahmed" />
</rewriter>
```

using asp.net 3.5
what is the problem , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many times have you read the message, and not noticed (much as with your username) that two of the letters are the wrong way around?

```
<rewrite url="~/User/Ahmed/ahmed.aspx" to="~/User/ahmed" />
```

Comment: sorry about that 2 days without sleep, thanks (my user name is meant to be that way not a mistake)

Comment: Even his username is misspelled. Haha. Epileptic much?